# Android how to show pop up on clicking CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, checkboxpreference

I have a PreferenceScreen in which i have a checkbox with the following code:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="the_key"
        android:summary="Random text here."
        android:title="My Title"
        />
```

I want a pop up message to be displayed on click of this checkbox that will have a set button and a cancel. If "set" will be pressed then the checkbox will be checked if previously unchecked and the opposite. How can i do that? Here is the code of my pop up message.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Some message that will be displayed")
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.set, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do something
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

Also how can i get the value of my checkbox(checked or not)?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To get checkbox is checked or not from CheckBoxPreference, use this

```
CheckBoxPreference pref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkbox_preference");
pref.isChecked(); //returns if it is checked or not
```

Comment: In this code i have an error in the findPreference saying:
Cannot resolve method findPreference.
Note that I'm trying to use that in the onCreateDialog method.

Comment: use the proper keyname

Comment: Done but still  that doesn't solve my other problem!

Comment: What is the other problem

Comment: As i mentioned i want a confirm dialog to be displayed in order for the value of the checkBoxPreference to be changed. Any idea how to do that?